# How can i parent the ThirdPersonController on when the player is on top of the Platform?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that detect when the player is collide with the Platform(Cube). But even if i touch it from the side the Platform it will show the Debug.Log and i want that only if the player is on top of the Platform only then show the Debug.Log when i mean on Top it's like in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I have a ThirdPersonController a Elevator(empty GameObject) Platform(Cube) Platform1(cube) and Button(Capsule).

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DetectPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Platform")
        {
            Debug.Log("On Platform");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, you have to use a combination of collider and a trigger to get what you want and this is one of those times.

**1**.Duplicate the *Platform* GameObject. Put the duplicated *Platform* under the original one then name it *OnTop Detector*.

**2**.Select the *OnTop Detector* GameObject and moving it up so that it is not touching the original *Platform* GameObject. Again make sure they are not touching but slightly above one another.

**4**.Scale the *OnTop Detector* GameObject so that it is smaller than the original *Platform* GameObject. The reason you do this is to make it so that it won't detect when on the side and touching but will detect when you are on top.

**5**.Check the *OnTop Detector* GameObject *Box Collider* as IsTrigger.

**6**.Add `OnTriggerEnter` to the code your question. `OnCollisionEnter` will be called when Player is touching the side of the *Platform*. `OnTriggerEnter` will be called when OnTop of the *Platform*.

**7**.Finally, you can now disable/remove the *Mesh Renderer* that is attached to the *OnTop Detector* GameObject. I usually only disable it so that I can enable it later on when I want to edit *OnTop Detector*'s collider with visual guide.

So, you use `OnTriggerEnter` to know when Player is on top of the Platform and `OnTriggerEnter` to know when it is touching the platform.

*Script*:

```
public class DetectPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Platform")
        {
            Debug.Log("Touching Platform");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "OnTop Detector")
        {
            Debug.Log("On Top of Platform");
        }
    }
}
```

Image Description of what I just said:

[image]